# How to determine if a force is making a difference

Tags: game-physics, farseer

I'm making a game in which I'm creating an animation system that speeds up based on the velocity of the character.

The problem is this won't work for the instance of a treadmill.

I do not have the speed of the treadmill, but I do have the force of the friction between the treadmill and the character.

I'm trying to determine if a force is making a difference. Knowing Only the forces that are being applied to an object, its weight, and its velocity, how would you determine if a single force is making a difference in it's velocity, and if so, how much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
F = m*a

a = d/dt v
```

With finite differences:

```
a = (v2-v1)/dt
```

And therefore the relationship:

```
F = m * (v2-v1)/dt
```

I hope, this helps :-)